# jquery mobile buttons not working when created dynamicaly

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, jquery-mobile-button

i m using jquery mobile ver. 1.3.0 i want to create  a button from jquery from my js file and want to show that button on my page but its not working.

Here is my jquery code to dynamicaly generate button:

```
<a href="'+ news.link + '" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">View</a>
```

its only shows the text not the button.

i think its because of the fact that the button is generated dynamicaly so its is unable to found the css in js file.thats why its not showing on page.coz on my page all buttons are working properly.

Comment: this should work http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Yb5B9/

Comment: @Omar :its workign bro but the button is not shoing properly .the text is showing above the button and buttons looking so small in comapre to text.

Comment: Pls show us your complete code.

Comment: @Omar : please help me.i just asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the button to the DOM,call trigger create method on the page to force JQM to reapply its styles.

```
$("#pageID").trigger("create");
```

Comment: thanks dear its working but the button is not showing properly.